# ListDensityPlot3D ColorFunction Interpolation

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, data, image3d

`ListDensityPlot3D` seems to do some sub-pixel colorfunction interpolation that results in an odd "halo" around some of the data.

```
tmp = Table[0, {20}, {20}, {20}];
tmp[[3 ;; 7, 3 ;; 7, 3 ;; 7]] = 1;
tmp[[13 ;; 17, 13 ;; 17, 13 ;; 17]] = 1;

ListDensityPlot3D[tmp, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 OpacityFunction -> Function[f, (f^0.4)], Background -> White, 
 Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> Large]
```

Is there a way to turn this interpolation off? Note: this is some toy data, the actual dataset is a bit different but the phenomena is the same.

Comment: you might consider `ListContourPlot3D` instead to get segmented regions, e.g. `ListContourPlot3D[tmp, ColorFunction ->"Rainbow", 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,Mesh->None,
  Background -> White,Contours->{1},
 Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> Large]`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. When I try is with my actual data, I get rather strange output because in each "region" there is sometimes a few lower values due to the nature of the data.

Comment: I would guess "strange output" with your actual data does not involve blending of colors as in `ListDensityPlot3D`? If it does, can you post a small example where this occurs?